# Data is returned from resource, but nothing displays

Tags: javascript, ruby, angularjs, sinatra

I have an AngularJS Frontend/Rails backend web app.

I posted my frontend code on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JL5s8/). My rails backend on the index page returns some json:

```
[{"id":1,"name":null,"user_id":null,"created_at":"2013-11-27T22:09:31Z","updated_at":"2013-11-27T22:09:31Z"},{"id":2,"name":null,"user_id":null,"created_at":"2013-11-27T22:22:55Z","updated_at":"2013-11-27T22:22:55Z"}]
```

On the network tab on Chrome Developer, it shows that the response is returning the correct JSON. There isn't any errors (at least that it shows), but nothing displays like it should when I use `{{row.id}}` or `{{row.created_at}}`, which are filled with data in the json.

Thanks for all help!

Comment: your fiddle is broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you are missing `$scope.$apply()` statement in your callback as the callback is from outside angularjs context. Try this

```
rowsService.fetchPopular(function(data){
   $scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.rows = data;
   });
});
```